# How to import a variable that is in a class, from one file to another?

Tags: python-3.x, file, class, tkinter, python-import

File 1

```
#file1
from tkinter import *

class UI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = Tk()
        sam = 'TestWord'
        import file2

    def run(self):
        self.main_window.mainloop()    

def main():
    ui = UI()
    ui.run()

main()
```

File 2

```
#file2
from file1 import sam
print(sam)
```

Output

```
from file1 import sam
builtins.ImportError: cannot import name 'sam'
```

How can I import sam when it is in a class? I know how to do this without the class present. Also, this code opens two GUI's which must be part of the problem, but I'm completely lost at this point. Do both variables have to be self.sam? So, self.sam = 'TestWord' and import self.sam. I have tried this and it didn't work, however, I might be missing a detail here. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

problem is `import file2` will not run the code for you. It happens only on python REPL.

you could do something like below,

**File1:**

```
from tkinter import *

class UI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = Tk()
        sam = 'TestWord'
        from file2 import foo
        foo(sam)

    def run(self):
        self.main_window.mainloop()    

def main():
    ui = UI()
    ui.run()

main()
```

**File2:**

```
def foo(sam):
    print(sam)
```

Answer (score 0):

So your `main()` doesn't run when you import file1, only when you run file1 use

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Additionally you can't access `sam` inside the class, this isn't a matter of files in this case, to access it from outside the class you either need to make it global, or use `self.sam = ...` and have an instance of your class.

Even better is to have file2 contain methods that use the `sam` value which you import into your file1.

Without seeing your actual use case I can't provide any other methods of achieving what you want, but you really should not make it global to access from another file.